# How to host and spectate with Hololens 1 using Azure Spatial Anchors?

Tags: unity-game-engine, hololens, mrtk, azure-spatial-anchors, mr-spectatorview

I am trying to share content between two hololens 1 headsets. To do this I am trying to use Azure spatial anchors with the MRTK in Unity. 
I am using unity 2018.4.14 with MRTK 2.0.0. 
I have followed the instructions [here](https://github.com/microsoft/MixedReality-SpectatorView/blob/master/README.md#getting-started-with-your-own-project) as well as [here](https://github.com/microsoft/MixedReality-SpectatorView/blob/master/doc/SpectatorView.Setup.md).
I have also tried the [Demo.2019 example](https://github.com/microsoft/MixedReality-SpectatorView/tree/master/samples/Build2019Demo.Unity)

The sections **HoloLens 2 & HoloLens as the Host/User** and **HoloLens 2 & HoloLens as a Spectator** from the spectator view setup make everything seem so simple but these steps are not working for me.

So far I have been unable to get anything to work, when I look at the Microsoft Azure spatial anchor metrics, no anchors have been created. I need help for hololens 1 and it seems as if most of the documentation is for hololens 2.

Any help would be very appreciated.

Comment: For development with HoloLens 1, please use the recommended Unity version 2018.4.x, which is the LTS build required for MRTK v2, check out details: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/install-the-tools. For the instructions about Spectator view, they mixed the guided steps of HL1 and HL2, the product team acknowledged this doc issue and will be updated later, but the main steps should work for HL1. So please try to use the recommended Unity and MRTKv2+ASA1.1 version and follow the steps.

Comment: My appologies for the Typo, I am using 2018.4.14 (LTS) as well as MRTK v2 and ASA1.1.0.

Comment: There are a lot of potential reasons things may not be working.

What branch are you using?

Did you run `Spectator View -> Update All Asset Caches` in the Unity Editor toolbar? Without this step, your local app content won't be synchronized across devices.

Did you setup your project to support ASA? Did you add the `SPATIALALIGNMENT_ASA` preprocessor directive to your WSA Player settings? Did you setup a SpatialAnchorsCoordinateLocalizationInitializer in your SpectatorView settings to contain your ASA account's id and key?

Comment: Did you declare the SpatialAnchorsCoordinateLocalizationInitializer as a PrioritizedInitializer in your SpatialLocalizationInitializationSettings? Did you build separate HoloLens applications, one containing your main Unity scene, the other containining the SpectatorView.HoloLens.SpectatorView scene? In the SpectatorView.HoloLens.SpectatorView scene, did you specify your main user's ip address in the SpectatorView prefab?